# When at lower pixels, website appears to shrink the size of a pixel?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive

Hi So I recently went back to a website i made a while ago using max width media query's and bootstrap 3.
I am now trying to use min screen media query's to make it fully responsive.

However even though the min width styles do get applied the screen never actually gets to those widths as it appears as the whole browser is just shrinking (like the size of a pixel) so even though the screen width may be at, for example, 320px wide within the screen the website has remained at 980px wide and is just smaller but still 980px.

So the window size is 320px and the website size is 980px? I am really confused and not sure how this is even possible.

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about. Sorry. Perhaps you could create a [mcve] and share it?

Comment: Sounds like you are missing the [viewport `<meta>` - W3C Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp)

Comment: Hello yes it is quite difficult to explain or even google as well. I can send a website and you can test it via chromes device emulator? would that be okay?

Comment: yes that is it!! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Going off what Ankith said in a comment, you should add this if you have not already to your head.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Comment: Yes this worked! thank you! i would mark this as the answer but i can't as i don't have enough points, but  thank you!